# Organic Chemistry - Reaction scheme and structures of molecules

Tags: organic-chemistry

Compound P and compound Q are straight-chain constitutional (structural) isomers with the
molecular formula C5H12O. Compound P can form optical isomers, whereas compound Q
cannot.
When reacted with concentrated sulfuric acid, compound P forms two products, compounds
R and S; compound Q forms only one product, compound S.

---

How come compound Q is pentan-1-ol and not pentan-3-ol?

Comment: @The_Vinz There is no much place for so- called geometrical isomerism here nor the text is suggesting that. You somehow mixed up description and nomenclature. OP should show some reasoning on h. side otherwise I'm afraid it is a homework Q

Comment: Woops you are right, I lost the point and misunderstood the question

Answer (score -1):

Q is pentan-1-ol and not pentan-3-ol as on dehydration, of pental-1-ol, only one product (alkene) is formed. Whereas on dehydration of pentan-3-ol, we get two alkenes, as the alkene can show geometrical isomerism.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Probably because  you have attacked the dehydration / geometrical isomerism issue,  too, without considering the optical isomerism.